# Unique background colours for pivot title area and content area

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app. I currently have a page with a Pivot control, which goes something like this:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="SomeApp.TestPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Chocolate">
        <phone:Pivot Title="DC UNIVERSE" Background="Chocolate">
            <phone:PivotItem x:Name="Batman" Header="Batman">
                <Grid x:Name="BatmanCharacterListPanel" Background="Beige">
                    <!--Some Content Here-->
                </Grid>
            </phone:PivotItem>
            <phone:PivotItem x:Name="Superman" Header="Superman">
                <Grid x:Name="SupermanCharacterListPanel" Background="Beige">
                    <!--Some Content Here-->
                </Grid>
            </phone:PivotItem>
        </phone:Pivot>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

When I switch between the two Pivot items I have the background colour showing up in between the pages. I do not want that. I want the flow to be one continuous Beige colour. In short, I want the Pivot to "look" like a Panorama during swipes.

Another way to put my question is how do I set a background colour for the header area of the Pivot Control alone and a different colour for the content area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you set the Background of the whole Pivot. Of course, until the content is not loaded, you will see that Background color. So you should apply the Background color for the Pivot Title and the PivotItem Header. You should take a look at this post to achive this: 
http://irisclasson.com/2015/01/03/changing-the-pivot-header-template-in-windows-phone-8-and-windows-phone-winrt/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the color of the pivot itself

```
<Pivot Background="Beige">
</Pivot>
```

Then to set the color of the header you can set a style for the

```
<Style TargetType="controlsPrimitives:PivotHeadersControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="controlsPrimitives:PivotHeadersControl">
                 <Grid Background="Red">
                     <Canvas x:Name="Canvas">
                         <ItemsPresenter/>
                     </Canvas>
                 </Grid>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You can find more detail about setting the backround of the headers at http://visuallylocated.com/post/2012/05/23/Changing-the-background-color-of-your-pivot-headers.aspx